# Kali Linux gray screen when booting

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I've just installed Kali Linux 2016.1. The installation was successful at first, the Grub worked normally.

But after that, quite often, when I boot I can't see the Grub screen, after a few seconds, I automatically enter the login screen of Linux, but half of the screen was static and become grayer and grayer, when I enter the root user and password, it's still login, but the screen now was fuzzing up and becomes grayer and grayer and I can't do anything with this.

I can't even access the BIOS (the words "Press ESC to enter BIOS", which normally appear when I start computer doesn't show up).

Sometimes I can enter Grub normally, but when I use Kali Linux, sometimes, a black screen appears in a second and then it returns to the normal screen.

I tried to search, but doesn't find any suitable solution.

I'm using HP Elitebook 8460.

Answer (score 0):

Since GNOME 3.16, GNOME Shell themes are now stored binary files (gresource).
You can find steps in ArchWiki under
[Autostarting applications with GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_logo)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue. I was able to resolve it by disabling the nouveau drivers.

Create a file /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf and paste the following lines:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
options nouveau.modeset=0
```

source: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/installing-nvidia-on-kali-2.0/